# oneArray's objects + twoAarray's objects to and of oneArray

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have two arrays're contained objects and i need to put elements(objects) to first array
How to do that ? mybe with underscore?

---

Comment: please add some data and the code you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain JS:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr1 = [6,7]
arr = arr.concat(arr1)
```

Using underscore

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr1 = [6,7]

arr.push(arr1)
arr = _.flatten(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

underscore / lodash is not required

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var numbers = numbers.concat(letters);

document.write(JSON.stringify(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge two array contaning objects, you have to choose field of object by which you want to merge.

```
array1 = [
 {field: 'username', display: 'username', hide: true},
 {field: 'age', display: 'Age', hide: true},
 {field: 'height', display: 'Height', hide: true}
]

array2 = [
{field: 'username', display: 'username 123', hide: false},
{field: 'age', hide: false}
]
```

Underscore -function-

```
_.values(_.extend(_.indexBy(array1, 'field'), _.indexBy(array2, 'field')))
```

We use indexBy to turn the arrays into objects keyed on the field value, and then extend does what we want. Finally, values turns it back into an array.

result -

```
 array3 = [
{field: 'username', display: 'username 123', hide: false},
{field: 'age', display: 'Age', hide: false},
{field: 'height', display: 'Height', hide: true}
]
```